# How to fill the time gap after grouping date record for months in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

I have table records as -

```
date                n_count
2020-02-19 00:00:00  4
2020-07-14 00:00:00  1
2020-07-17 00:00:00  1
2020-07-30 00:00:00  2
2020-08-03 00:00:00  1
2020-08-04 00:00:00  2
2020-08-25 00:00:00  2
2020-09-23 00:00:00  2
2020-09-30 00:00:00  3
2020-10-01 00:00:00  11
2020-10-05 00:00:00  12
2020-10-19 00:00:00  1
2020-10-20 00:00:00  1
2020-10-22 00:00:00  1
2020-11-02 00:00:00  376
2020-11-04 00:00:00  72
2020-11-11 00:00:00  1
```

I want to be grouped all the records into months for finding month total count which is working, but there is a missing of month. how to fill this gap.

```
time           month_count
"2020-02-01"    4
"2020-07-01"    4
"2020-08-01"    5
"2020-09-01"    5
"2020-10-01"    26
"2020-11-01"    449
```

This is what I have tried.

```
SELECT (date_trunc('month', date))::date AS time,
       sum(n_count) as month_count      
FROM table1
group by time
order by time asc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` to generate all starts of months between the earliest and latest date available in the table, then bring the table with a `left join`:

```
select d.dt, coalesce(sum(t.n_count), 0) as month_count      
from (
    select generate_series(date_trunc('month', min(date)), date_trunc('month', max(date)), '1 month') as dt 
    from table1
) as d(dt)
left join table1 t on t.date >= d.dt and t.date < d.dt + interval '1 month'
group by d.dt
order by d.dt
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply `UNION` a date series, generated from `MIN` and `MAX` date:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7495eb2df6254b77c966704c27506a98)

```
WITH cte AS (                                      -- 1
    SELECT
        *,
        date_trunc('month', date)::date AS time
    FROM
        t
)
SELECT 
    time,
    SUM(n_count) as month_count                    --3
FROM (
    SELECT
        time,
        n_count
    FROM cte

    UNION

    SELECT                                        -- 2
        generate_series(
            (SELECT MIN(time) FROM cte),
            (SELECT MAX(time) FROM cte),
            interval '1 month'
        )::date,
        0
) s
GROUP BY time
ORDER BY time
```

1. Use CTE to calculate date_trunc only once. Could be left out if you like to call your table twice in the `UNION` below
2. Generate monthly date series from `MIN` to `MAX` date containing your `n_count value = 0`. Add it to the table
3. Do your calculation

Comment: Thank you. This actually solved my problem.